# extract file timestamp of multiple files batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timestamp

My task is to extract the timestamp of all the files that are stored in a txt file (with full path). I'm using for loop to do this, but I always get incorrect date and time. Here's what I have written:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (D:\Balaji\filepath\output3.txt) do call :Sub2 %%a
goto :eof

:Sub2
echo.
if exist %1 (
    echo File %1 has arrived update the DB.
    FOR %%f IN (%1) DO (
        SET filedatetime=%%~tf
    )
    echo Datetime of %1 is: %filedatetime%
)
```

The result I get is the modified date/time of the second file in the list rather than the first one. Where am I going wrong?

Result:

> ```
> File D:\folder\test.txt has arrived update the DB.
> Datetime of D:\folder\test.txt is:
>
> File D:\folder\filenames.sql has arrived update the DB.
> Datetime of D:\folder\filenames.sql is: 10/19/2016 03:53 PM
>
> File D:\folder\test1.txt has arrived update the DB.
> Datetime of D:\folder\test1.txt is: 12/22/2016 02:20 PM
>
> File D:\folder\file.csv has arrived update the DB.
> Datetime of D:\folder\file.csv is: 12/22/2016 04:50 PM
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add option `"delims="` to `for /F` to not split paths containing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> characters.
2. Use `"%~1"` rather than `%1` to avoid trouble with special characters like e. g. `^` `&` `(` `)`.
3. In your code, either use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for variable `filedatetime`, or reverse the `if` query to `if not exist "%~1" goto :EOF` to avoid `filedatetime` to be changed and read in the same parenthesised block of code.
   Anyway, there is actually no need for the `for` loop as the `~t` modifier is also supported by argument references like `%1`.

So here is the fixed code:

```bat
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("D:\Balaji\filepath\output3.txt") do call :Sub2 "%%A"
goto :EOF

:Sub2
echo/
if not exist "%~1" goto :EOF
echo File "%~1" has arrived update the DB.
echo Datetime of "%~1" is: %~t1
```

Actually, you do not even need the sub-routine for this:

```bat
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("D:\Balaji\filepath\output3.txt") do (
    echo/
    if exist "%%~A" (
        echo File "%%~A" has arrived update the DB.
        echo Datetime of "%%~A" is: %%~tA
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:Sub2
echo.
if NOT exist %1 GOTO :EOF
echo File %1 has arrived update the DB.
FOR %%f IN (%1) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf
echo Datetime of %1 is: %filedatetime%
```

or

```
:Sub2
echo.
if NOT exist %1 GOTO :EOF
echo File %1 has arrived update the DB.
FOR %%f IN (%1) DO echo Datetime of %1 is: %%~tf
```

The problem is `delayedexpansion` - many SO items on this. `%var%` is replaced in a block (parenthesised sequence of lines) with its *value* at the time the *outermost* block was encountered. There are ways around - read more SO items about `delayed expansion`